# Spring Boot: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I´m writing a sample project for my personal blog about how to use Spring Boot from scratch. At this moment trying to save my entities on a H2 database, I am receiving this mapping exception from the class BulkController which is RestController class trying to save instances of my `Document` POJO class.

Here is the code of `GET` method using double brace initialization:

```
Iterable<Document> records = csvParser.getRecords()
        .stream()
        .skip(1)
        .map(record -> new Document() {{
            setSource(record.get(0));
            setCodeListCode(record.get(1));
            setCode(record.get(2));
            setDisplayValue(record.get(3));
            setLongDescription(record.get(4));
        }})
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

documentRepository.saveAll(records);
```

Checking the raised exception:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.josephrodriguez.learning.springboot.controller.BulkController$1
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.entityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:704) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1608) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
```

Some part of me felt some curiosity to check the class of Iterable items.

```
    for (Document d: records) {
        System.out.println(d.getClass());
    }
```

As I suspected, this was the output:

```
class com.josephrodriguez.learning.springboot.controller.BulkController$1
```

Removing the use of `map` function everything works fine.

**Question**: Why the `map` function with the double brace initialization changes the class type of the expected items of the collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new Document() {...}` is an anonymous class and since I suppose your code is executed in `...BulkController` it is called as `...BulkController$1` and hence is not recognized by Hibernate as a managed type. Doesn't matter whether it is `new Document {}` or `new Document {{}}`.

Implement an adequate constuctor/wither/builder/setter function for `Document` class and everything should work just fine.

Eg. using `lombok.Builder`:

```
@Builder
public class Document {...}


...
    Iterable<Document> records = csvParser.getRecords()
        .stream()
        .skip(1)
        .map(record ->
             Document.builder()
                 .source(record.get(0))
                 .codeListCode(record.get(1))
                 .code(record.get(2))
                 .displayValue(record.get(3))
                 .longDescription(record.get(4))
                 .build()
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    documentRepository.saveAll(records);
```

P.S. Idk how you made it work removing `map`, but `JpaRepository<Document, ID>` would always expect an `Iterable<Document>` parameter.

Comment: Good answer, I will use the builder pattern that you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

My answer : `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity` exception occurs because persistence Context doesn't manage BulkController$1.

Like mention of Serg Vasylchak above, `{{ }}` (double brace) creates an anoymous class derived outer class. ex. BulkController. But persistence context doesn't know about the type of Bulkcontroller.

So it works when you remove `map` logic, because double brace initialization is located in `map`. Why don't you create Document class through `builder` recommended by Serg Vasylchark?